# command error *incorrect syntax near ','*

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010

```
 Dim Query As String
 Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Minimarket;Integrated Security=True")
        Query = "INSERT INTO Barang(kode_bar,kode_kat,nama_bar,satuan, hbeli, hjual, stok, expired)VALUES("
        Query = Query + txtkodebar.Text + ",'" + cmbkodekat.Text + "','" + txtnamabar.Text + "','" + txtsatuan.Text + "','" + txthbeli.Text + "','" + txthjual.Text + "','" + txtstok.Text + "','" + Format(dtpex.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'"
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, con)
        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Data gagal disimpan")
        End If
        con.Close()
```

*there is anyone can help me ? when i press button save there is error incorrect syntax near ',' in cmd.executenonquery . what i must doing now ? i fell give up :'( *

Comment: **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!!!](http://bobby-tables.com/)** Apologies for the shouting, but this is **so** important, not just for security but for performance too. Parameterised queries are properly typed, and can re-used cached plans. There is not a single good reason not to use them.

Comment: `Query = Query + txtkodebar.Text + ",'"` you are missing quotes around `txtkodebar.Text`

Comment: Aside from your problem this code is open to SQL Injection attacks.  You never want to take user text and include it directly as inline string.  Here is an article that explains the problem your code has: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/04/01/security-code-review-techniques-sql-injection-edition.aspx

Comment: Also add a ) at the end. Btw, yes, start using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between expired) and VALUES, you are also missing quotes around txtkodebar.Text, see corrected codebelow:

```
 Dim Query As String
 Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Minimarket;Integrated Security=True")
    Query = "INSERT INTO Barang(kode_bar,kode_kat,nama_bar,satuan, hbeli, hjual, stok, expired) VALUES("
    Query = Query + "'" + txtkodebar.Text + "','" + cmbkodekat.Text + "','" + txtnamabar.Text + "','" + txtsatuan.Text + "','" + txthbeli.Text + "','" + txthjual.Text + "','" + txtstok.Text + "','" + Format(dtpex.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')"
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, con)
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Data gagal disimpan")
    End If
    con.Close()
```

As stated by @GarethD, you should also read upon parametrised queries, as your current query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: i have change like ur suggest but there is still error command in *Incorrect syntax near 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.*
i think that format was correct for data table type "datetime", but why that's format still incorrect ? :o

Comment: Can you post the content of Query ?

Comment: I have corrected the code above, I have added a closing braked ) after the  the datime.

Comment: what u mean of post content of query ?

Comment: What is the value of the variable Query in your script ? It looks like there is still something wrong with the SQL query you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is this part of your query:

```
Query = Query + txtkodebar.Text + ",'"
```

This results in no quotes around `txtkodebar.Text`. You could fix this by changing it to this:

```
Query = Query + "'" + txtkodebar.Text + "','"
```

but a far better way to fix this would be to use parameterized queries, which would not only make this query much less prone to errors, it also eliminates a very bad security hole you have here. What would happen if someone passed "`dummy','2015-01-01');DROP DATABASE;`" into txtstok.Text?

Comment: oh God....i made the impossible code...sorry... huft... this code feeling so hard...

Answer (score 0):

The chances are you have something like `O'shea` in one of your text boxes, which means that because you are using string concatenation to build your query string rather than parameters you end up with an incorrect string.

If you switch to using proper parameterised queries, you will remove the chances of this happening, and will send a properly formatted SQL Statement to the server:

```
Dim Query As String
Query = "INSERT INTO Barang(kode_bar,kode_kat,nama_bar,satuan, hbeli, hjual, stok, expired)" & _
        "VALUES(@kode_bar,@kode_kat,@nama_bar,@satuan, @hbeli, @hjual, @stok, @expired)"

Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Minimarket;Integrated Security=True")
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kode_bar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtkodebar.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@kode_kat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cmbkodekat.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nama_bar", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtnamabar.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@satuan", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtsatuan.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@hbeli", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txthbeli.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@hjual", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txthjual.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stok", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtstok.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@expired", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dtpex.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing)

        conn.Open()
        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If (i > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Data gagal disimpan")
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

I have had to guess at your data types, but it should be fairly clear how to switch between different types. It is also about 5 years since I wrote anything in VB.NET so please forgive any syntax errors.

Comment: yea...that's code can resolution from incorrect syntax near ";" but there is another error command like this "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." i dont know what happend with that format cz i thinked was correct for datatype datetime...

Comment: I think that error comes from this: `DateTime.ParseExact(dtpex.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing)`, are you sure `dtpex.Text` is a valid datetime?

Comment: i have check in mydatabase sql server, the datatype was datetime so in visual basic 2010 i use date time picker(dtpex.text) for input date of expired the things i wan insert in mydatabase...